# Display two sets of data in same ui grid with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-grid

I am new to AngularJS and UI Grid. I have a UI grid that displays ~ 30,000 rows the issue is it takes ~ 10 to 15 seconds to load the grid as the data is read from a table (Created indexes on the table to improve the performance after which it takes 10 to 15 seconds) to display all the data. To solve this issue what we planned is to display ~9000 rows (One day's worth of data) on initial load and have a button click to display all the data later. Here the grid will be the same but the number of rows loading on the grid should be changed. Button click should call a stored procedure and this data should be binded to the same grid. How to achieve this? Any help is appreciated. I have searched forums for solution but didn't find any links to solve this issue.

Comment: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/112_swapping_data shows how to change the data for the ui-grid. How to call a stored procedure via a button click is quite broad and depends on your server-side language/framework.

Comment: Thanks for the response MIke..Sorry if My question wasn't clear..I am aware of the process to call a stored proc edure, my question is how to display it in the grid? Should I be using if else statement if yes how to implement this?..Thanks for the swapping link.. Will try that and let you know in some time.

Comment: Working with large data sets on grids, I always look for a server-side pagination. [UI Grid supports it](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/314_external_pagination), so you will need to prepare your backend side to receive the additional parameters and return the correct data for each page.

Comment: Thanks Mike McCaughan. That worked like a charm :)

Comment: @elvin : This might be ideal solution for my application. Will try this out in couple of days. Thanks for your response.